# Disable Certain Keyboard Keys at Lock Screen

Tags: windows-10

This is a tricky one,

Does windows 10 have a setting implemented which prevents the user from using the fn keys/fixed feature keys when the computer is locked.

I have googled around but the results are irrelevent things such as 'how to disable lock screen' or 'how to change the vokume limit', etc.

Examples of what the function keys can do even the the computer is locked:

- change/mute volume
- turn airplane mode on/off
- change screen brightness
- enable/disable keyboard backlight
- skip foward/back a track
- play/pause a track
- connect to a remote display/projector
- custom key mapping and/or custom keyboard shortcut actions as the NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM user (dangerous)

Any ideas?

Comment: These are going to be difficult to pin down because the implementation varies by manufacturer and model.

Comment: You can only disable the key via keyboard filter feature if you use Windows 10 Enterprise or Education. But this is for whole Windows not only lock screen.